# async function that gets data from firestore executing multiple times in dart/flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I have a piece of code here that is supposed to get some data from firebase firestore and add that data to a list which is then in turn is used by listview.builder to update the ui with the list of items. But somehow, the same data keeps getting added to the list over and over again. I put a print statement and i can see that the code inside the "then" function keeps executing over and over. How do i stop this from happening?
Thanks in advance

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import '../models/reportmodel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AllReports extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AllReportsState createState() => _AllReportsState();
}

class _AllReportsState extends State<AllReports> {
  List<Report> reportList = [];
  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData();
    return (isLoading)
        ? buildLoading()
        : ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 140,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Complaint ID: " + reportList[index].getComplaintHash(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Name: " + reportList[index].getComplainantName(),
                    ),
                    Text("Time: " + reportList[index].getComplaintTime()),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
            itemCount: reportList.length);
  }

  Widget buildLoading() => Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        ],
      );

  void getData() async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(user.email)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((snapshot) {
      for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.documents.length; i++) {
        reportList.add(Report.addData(
            snapshot.documents[i].id.toString(),
            snapshot.documents[i].data()["name"].toString(),
            snapshot.documents[i].data()["contact"].toString(),
            snapshot.documents[i].data()["time"].toString(),
            snapshot.documents[i].data()["description"].toString(),
            snapshot.documents[i].data()["additional_info"].toString()));
      }
      this.setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, there. I just want to ask how many items in your data? Because I think that the loop inside of the "getData()" is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's getting executed over and over again, because you are calling the method `getData()` inside the `build()`, and everytime you call `setState` then it issues another build.Therefore, the method `getData()` will keep executing and retrieving the data.

You should use `FutureBuilder` widget to handle asynchronous operations.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Was about to write the same, but as a german proverb says: "The early bird catches the worm"